# How to remove an attribute from RequestSpecification/FilterableRequestSpecification body?

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Dears,

I am working on creating a simple method which will take String argument which will be a path or other kind "pointer" to attribute/s in JSON and this method will remove those attribute/s.

My problem is I can find values of those attribute/s using JsonPath, but I can't find methods in rest assured (or other libraries) which could remove/delete attributes by given path.
JSON is already added earlier so i need to pull him from RequestSpecification or FilterableRequestSpecification object ex.

```
RequestSpecification rs = *objFromContext*;
FilterableRequestSpecification frs= (FilterableRequestSpecification) rs;
frs.getBody();
```

I've tried to work with JSONObject class and remove() but it doesn't work on complex JSONs.

given example JSON

```
{
    "created": "string",
    "updated": "string",
    "items": [
        {
            "code": "TEST",
            "nested": {
                "code": "test",
                "name": "name",
                "other": [
                    {
                        "code": "TEST",
                        "name": "myName",
                        "quantity": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            "itemsProperties": [
                {
                    "code": "value1",
                    "name": "name",
                    "value": 123
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "code": "TEST",
            "nested": {
                "code": "test",
                "name": "name",
                "other": [
                    {
                        "code": "TEST",
                        "name": "myName",
                        "quantity": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            "itemsProperties": [
                {
                    "code": "value2",
                    "name": "name",
                    "value": 123
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "timer": {
        "startDate": "2015-01-01",
        "endDate": "2021-01-02"
    },
    "id": "myId"
}
```

using `JsonPath jp = JsonPath.from(httpRequest.getBody().toString());`
and then `jp.get(items.itemsproperties.code)` i can find value1 and value2.
**I stuck in this point: How to remove those attributes from sended body?** 
I know i can convert body into JSONObject and then go field after field conversion between getJSONArray and GetJSONOBject and remove those fields, but i would like to make this metod much more universal. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manipulate json in Rest-Assured JsonPath, then the answer is No. You can't do that. JsonPath help you to extract value from json, that's it, no more.

You have to use different libraries to remove key-value pair.

For example: using [JsonPath Jayway](https://github.com/lucas-nguyen-17/JsonPath/tree/master)

```
DocumentContext parse = JsonPath.parse(body);
parse.delete("$..itemsProperties..code");
System.out.println(parse.jsonString());
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems it is my dreamed solution.

Comment: @BartoszOlczak Did you miss upvote or accept the answer?

Comment: upvoted and accepted. Thanks!